# Have an ascx control with retrieved values displayed. Want to use a text input box to post back as value changes

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, search, postback

So I'm working on something that involves taking user input from some sort of text input, and as the user types into the box, firing off events to update the displayed list on the fly.

My particular hangup is figuring out how to display an input text box in html, and have it post back to the code behind every time the user enters or deletes a character (basically, whenever the value of the text changes) to update my list.

I initially tried looking at HtmlInputText, but it does not do any post back on it's own so I don't think this is what I'm looking for.

What type of element & interactions should I be looking at?

thanks!

Comment: I think you should look to use javascript and async calls(ajax) for this. If you are using aspx, then jquery can be used. Don't try to do call backs to do a seach on every change of the criteria by the user, it will very slow and very poor experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `OnTextChanged` function to call the code behind & set `AutoPostBack` as true.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="InputBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="InputBox1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Code Behind

```
 protected void InputBox1_TextChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
         //You're code here
    }
```